# How can i set number in phone dialer screen programatically while in telephone call?

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager

I am trying to set number of phone dialer programatically while in telephone call on Android but i could not find a solution for a while.

I'm using this code for set the phone dialer and call when the user call the given number:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:04445556677"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Also, i can use ACTION_DIAL instead of ACTION_CALL for set the phone dialer while in the idle and i can set phone dialer with it but i can not set the phone dialer while in the phone call.

Furthermore, this is my call receiver class:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
private static Date callStartTime;
private static boolean isIncoming;
private static String savedNumber;



@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Log.w("intent " , intent.getAction().toString());


    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
        savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");//buda çekiyor sanırsam

    } else {
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);//tel numarasını çekiyor
        int state = 0;
        if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;

        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        }

        onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
    }
}



public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
    if (lastState == state) {
        //No change, debounce extras
        return;
    }
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
            callStartTime = new Date();
            savedNumber = number;

            Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming Call Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
            if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                isIncoming = false;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing Call Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
            if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing but no pickup" + savedNumber + " Call time " + callStartTime + " Date " + new Date(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (isIncoming) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming " + savedNumber + " Call time " + callStartTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(context, "outgoing " + savedNumber + " Call time " + callStartTime + " Date " + new Date(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            break;
    }
    lastState = state;
}
```

}

I hope that somebody could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have this permission in your manifest : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission> ?

Comment: Yes, I have that permission in my manifest. Also, i have these permissions:  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing between two very similar activities, but still very different:

1. The `Phone`'s dialer - allows the user to call some phone number
2. The `InCallUi`'s dialer - allows the user to send keytones during the call for navigating menus.

The first one is set to receive the `ACTION_CALL` / `ACTION_DIAL` intents, the second one has no broadcast intents set, so you can't manipulate it.

Comment: Can we still get the incallui's packageid?